# Error installation Sitecore 9.1

Tags: sitecore-install-framework, installation

[image]

I tried to install sitecore 9.1 but I got this error so unable to install, please help me

Comment: Welcome to the community Divya. Would you mind posting the exception as text rather just screen shot? This will make question more searchable for future references. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

This error belongs to your windows user permissions. Just be sure that you run PowerShell as Administrator.

*(When you call SetAccessRule() to set access rights on a windows file/directory, the user who will get the permission has to be a member of the Administrators group. If the user is not a member of the Administrators group PowerShell shows the error message Exception calling "SetAccessRule" with "1" argument(s): "Some or all identity references could not be translated.")*

Comment: +1 for adding the actual text of the error so others can find it in the future.